# How do I tell if a float is a whole number?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to determine whether or not a person can participate in an activity based on their height. If their height in centimeters/inches/whatever is a perfect square, then they can go, if not, they can't. This is what I have now:

```
print "Input height here:"

def height_input
    input = gets.to_i
    input**0.5
end

if height_input.integer?
    print "Congrats, you're in!"
else
    print "Sorry, we can't let you in."
end
```

The `if` statement doesn't work the way I want because the method returns a float value (example: `input = 64` => `8.0`) and not a whole integer. If I add (`to_i`) to the end of the method, or if I call the method to make the value an integer, it gives me the first digit of the root in integer form. That isn't bad if I do in fact have a perfect square, but if it's not a perfect square, then I get the same result as if I did. Help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (height_input % 1).zero?
```

or

```
if height_input.to_i == height_input
```

Comment: Also `height_input.round == height_input`, `height_input.ceil == height_input` and `height_input.floor == height_input` (the last being the same as `height_input.to_i == height_input`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Also `Integer(height_input) == height_input`.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, the last statement in a method block is it's return value.

```
def height_input
    input = gets.to_i
    input**0.5
end
```

That means `(input ** 0.5)` is what's being returned here. This returns a floatation point number. We need to convert that to an integer as well

```
(input ** 0.5).to_i
```

Now, the return value will be `8`.

Comment: I tried that and it does give me the integer, but I specifically need the integer if it is a whole number, otherwise I need it to give me the float so that the if-statement puts the correct message.